# Formula to Test for Blanks in two Columns Against a Third Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am using a conditional formatting custom formula to highlight a cell if the column it is summing from another spreadsheet has blanks, but I don't know how to do it with changing ranges. Basically what I want to do is use a third column, say column A, to determine the length of the range (of rows) I want to scan with CountBlank, and if it picks up a blank in there to return a "True".

So basically:

```
Column A     Column B      Column C      Column D
Person 1       5:30AM       3:00PM         9.5 
Person 2       5:00AM                       8
Person 3       4:30AM       4:00PM        10.5
```

So ideally, the cell sums the fourth column with a different function (already have that), and it conditionally formats itself if a blank is picked up in Columns B or C, going all the way down to the last row of column A that has a value. Any help here would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the custom formula for conditional formatting should be:

```
=or(countifs(A2:A,"<>",B2:B,""),countifs(A2:A,"<>",C2:C,""))
```

[image]

Suppose you had a list of people's names starting in F2 and their total hours starting in G2. Then you could alter the formula to:

```
=or(countifs(A$2:A,F2,B$2:B,""),countifs(A$2:A,F2,C$2:C,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom, that's exactly what I wanted! One last question, would there be a way to specify it a little more depending on the name in column A? So say I just wanted my cell to highlight if Person 2 missed a punch during the week. So picture column A being full of Persons 1, 2, and 3 with their respective time in and time out for columns B&C respectively. I would like the cell cell that sums their hours to format itself if say one day during the week just Person 2 missed one punch or more. Im really appreciative of your help, I'm just new to cond. formatting :(

Comment: Will add to my answer